# Links not clickable on mobile devices in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am experiencing weird behaviour with links in WordPress. See attached screenshot. The links in the piece of text are clickable on desktop, but when switching to mobile they can not be clicked anymore.

[image]

I inspected the element to check if some z-index or layer is blocking it, but I can't seem to find it. Also the rest of the blocks in the website click fine on mobile.

If you want to try for yourself, website link: https://www.keeperstalent.nl
The part that gives trouble is on the homepage somewhere around the middle.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: lol calm down it was just to show where the area is of the issue because the website is not in English.. There was no error in the console

Comment: You still have issues because you have not posted a [mcve] with your markup and code here within your question and not an image or link to any third party source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have a problem with columns overlap.

[image: Columns overlap on mobile]
[image: Columns on desktop are side by side]

All you need to do is to make these two columns to have the same classes:

```
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6 vc_col-lg-6 vc_col-md-6 vc_col-xs-12">
```

Though Andrey's answer will do the trick it may lead to undesirable consequences like this:

[image: links are over the header]

Now all links are placed over your header and popups

Comment: Great notice, though the "undesirable consequences" can be fixed by changing `z-index` to a desired value.

Comment: Thanks man!! I noticed the problem for the other fix indeed. This is the right solution.

Comment: Hi @Rob, you're taking it wrong, it's a help page about "how to ask," section "Help others reproduce the problem." It has nothing to do with my answer. Nonetheless, I have posted all the code needed and typed the description of the problem and the solution, so my answer carries the message even without all the images.

Comment: Before your edit, if one removed your image, would it provide an answer to the question? That was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it by adding:

```
a {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
z-index: 2;
}
```

I'm not sure what was the problem, I just noticed that it works. And it only works with all of the three properties.

Comment: @RafRasenberg as @Cheslab mentioned, there is not need for `z-index` to be set so high because it overlaps with the header. So be sure to assign a lower value to `z-index` of your `<a>`  than to `z-index` of your header. I just checked your website again, and it looks like even `z-index: 2;` for `<a>` works.

Comment: Imagine there's a button tomorrow. You'll have to add same css for buttons? What about `input`s, `textarea`s, other clickable elements? Don't forget that `div`s can be clickable with js, as well as any other element. I think restore the normal flow of the document is a much preferable solution.

Comment: @Cheslab Of course making HTML and CSS valid is a preferable solution, but sometimes it's not possible to edit HTML because of using different kind of builders, plugins, etc.